# Service Fabric StatelessService multiple listeners types not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

### Goal

I have a `StatelessService` in a cluster, with the core functionality of listening to, and handling Azure Service Bus messages. However, I also want this `StatelessService` to be able to listen to an internal broker service of the cluster (SoCreate's Pub/Sub Broker).

### What works

When I register the listeners of different types separately (two custom Service Bus listeners or one internal broker listener of type `FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener`), they work. But when I try to have all three at the same time, the broker fails to deliver messages to the `StatelessService`.

##### Service Bus Listeners

I set up the working subscribers to Azure Service Bus messages from the two subscriptions, by registering a custom Service Bus listener for each. These implements the `ICommunicationListener` interface. I create them by overriding the `CreateServiceInstanceListeners` method as follows:

```cs
private readonly ServiceBusHandler1 _handler1 = new();
private readonly ServiceBusHandler2 _handler2 = new();

protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    var serviceInstanceListeners = new List<ServiceInstanceListener>();
           
    serviceInstanceListeners.Add(new ServiceInstanceListener(context => 
        new ServiceBusCommunicationListener(_handler1, /*some other input params*/), name: "ServiceBusListener1"));
    
    serviceInstanceListeners.Add(new ServiceInstanceListener(context => 
        new ServiceBusCommunicationListener(_handler2, /*some other input params*/), name: "ServiceBusListener2"));
       
    return serviceInstanceListeners;
}
```

##### `FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener` listener

Similarly, I register the working listener to the internal broker as follows:

```cs
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    var serviceInstanceListeners = new List<ServiceInstanceListener>();
           
    serviceInstanceListeners.Add(new ServiceInstanceListener(context => 
        new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this), name: "SubscriberStatelessServiceRemotingListener"));
       
    return serviceInstanceListeners;
}
```

### What doesn't work

The internal broker fails to deliver the messages in the queue when I combine the listeners:

```cs
private readonly ServiceBusHandler1 _handler1 = new();
private readonly ServiceBusHandler2 _handler2 = new();

protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    var serviceInstanceListeners = new List<ServiceInstanceListener>();
           
    serviceInstanceListeners.Add(new ServiceInstanceListener(context => 
        new ServiceBusCommunicationListener(_handler1, /*some other input params*/), name: "ServiceBusListener1"));
    
    serviceInstanceListeners.Add(new ServiceInstanceListener(context => 
        new ServiceBusCommunicationListener(_handler2, /*some other input params*/), name: "ServiceBusListener2"));

    serviceInstanceListeners.Add(new ServiceInstanceListener(context => 
        new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this), name: "SubscriberStatelessServiceRemotingListener"));
       
    return serviceInstanceListeners;
}
```

I recognize that this is a question that I might have to raise with the Broker package team, but I'd just like to make sure that there isn't something Service Fabric-related I'm missing first.

I'm running a local, 1 Windows node cluster

Comment: I found a working solution. I will add a detailed response as soon as I get the time.

Answer (score 0):

I've has a quick look at some similar code of mine, so in case anyone else drops by, you could try something like this:

```
private readonly ServiceBusHandler1 _handler1 = new();
private readonly ServiceBusHandler2 _handler2 = new();

protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    var serviceInstanceListeners = this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners();
           
    serviceInstanceListeners.Add(new ServiceInstanceListener(context => 
        new ServiceBusCommunicationListener(_handler1, /*some other input params*/), name: "ServiceBusListener1"));
    
    serviceInstanceListeners.Add(new ServiceInstanceListener(context => 
        new ServiceBusCommunicationListener(_handler2, /*some other input params*/), name: "ServiceBusListener2"));
       
    return serviceInstanceListeners;
}
```

... note - rather than tagging the remoting listener on to the end manually, just use the base `CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners` method to set this up - it returns a collection of listeners, then just bolt your SB listeners on to the end of the list ... works for me :)